# django page object is not iterable with pagination example

Tags: django, pagination, view

Following this example,

[Pagination example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs)

I tried to use it with one of my models.

```
def index(request):
    firstTen = Person.objects.all()
    pagination = Paginator(firstTen, 2)

    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        people = pagination.page('page')
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        people = pagination.page(1)


    return render_to_response('index.html', {'people': people},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

For some reason i am getting `'Page' object is not iterable` when using it in my view like so

```
{% for result in people %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: people = pagination.page('page') should be people = pagination.page(page)

Comment: Changing this gives me another error about page not being, int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Never mind, Thanks Michael Dunn. Post your solution and i will accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your script: The line `people = pagination.page('page')` should be `people = pagination.page(page)`. The clue from the error message is that it's expecting a `Page` object, and whatever it got didn't seem to act like one.